# CustomMessageBox from Windows Phone 8 Toolkit throw NullPointerException

Tags: c#, windows-phone, windows-phone-8

Code for creating the `CustomMessageBox`:

`CustomMessageBox` is a property, and not a reference to the C# Class in the Toolkit.

```
CustomMessageBox.Dismissed += (dismissSender, dismissedEvent) =>
{
    switch (dismissedEvent.Result)
    {
        case CustomMessageBoxResult.LeftButton:
            PlaceCall(clickedFavorite.Name, clickedFavorite.PhoneNo);
            break;
        case CustomMessageBoxResult.RightButton:
            HERE ---> SendText(clickedFavorite.PhoneNo);
            break;
    }
};
```

Code for `SendText()` method:

```
private void SendText(String phoneNo)
{
    var smsTask = new SmsComposeTask
                      {
                          To = phoneNo
                      };

    smsTask.Show();
}
```

Thing is when the `SmsComposeTask` has started, the Phone navigates to the SMS application, which is correct.

If the user then decides to go back, with the Hardware Back Button, the SMS application closes and the phone shows my app again - but immediately closes, caused by a NullPointerException:

```
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.CustomMessageBox.ClosePopup(Boolean restoreOriginalValues)
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.CustomMessageBox.<>c__DisplayClass4.<Dismiss>b__1(Object s, EventArgs e)
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Transition.OnCompleted(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at MS.Internal.CoreInvokeHandler.InvokeEventHandler(Int32 typeIndex, Delegate handlerDelegate, Object sender, Object args)
   at MS.Internal.JoltHelper.FireEvent(IntPtr unmanagedObj, IntPtr unmanagedObjArgs, Int32 argsTypeIndex, Int32 actualArgsTypeIndex, String eventName)
```

I have also tried to override the `OnBackKeyPress` event, like this:

```
protected override void OnBackKeyPress(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (CustomMessageBox != null && CustomMessageBox.IsEnabled)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
    else
    {
        base.OnBackKeyPress(e);
    }
}
```

**Does anyone know what to do?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a solution to my own problem. Instead of using the faulty `CustomMessageBox`, I found [Coding4Fun Windows Phone Toolkit](http://coding4fun.codeplex.com/releases/view/92875) which provides a by far, more stable message box called `MessagePrompt` - here's how to use it.

**Create buttons**

```
var smsButton = new Button { Content = "SMS" };
smsButton.Click += (o, args) =>
{
    // do something
};

var buttonList = new List<Button>
{
    smsButton
};
```

**Create the actual message prompt**

```
var msgPrompt = new MessagePrompt
{
    Title = "Message Prompt Title",
    Body = new TextBlock { Text = "Text for the Body", FontSize = 25, TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap },
    ActionPopUpButtons = buttonList
};
```

**Show it**

```
msgPrompt.Show()
```

**No bullocks**

The good thing, which I have experienced with this `MessagePrompt` is that you are not bound to two static **Left** and **Right** buttons like with `CustomMessageBox`.

And if you want, you can set the `Body` property to a whole new XAML page, which makes this control flexible.

Reference: [Coding4Fun WP7 Message Prompt in depth](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Coding4Fun-WP7-Message-Prompt-in-depth)

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't this problem has something to do with Windows Phone Application lifecycle. As can be found [here, figure 6](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsphonetrainingcourse_applicationlifetimewp7lab_topic2.aspx). When activiting another program when your program is active you should save all application data so when a reactivating event ,such as navigating with your back button back to your application, starts your program again you can load the user's data again.

Comment: Now I'm already thinking, what I can do to save a _property_ in the application's data?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what's happening, but you can just delay the SMS task to avoid the issue:

```
CustomMessageBox.Dismissed += (dismissSender, dismissedEvent) =>
{
    switch (dismissedEvent.Result)
    {
        case CustomMessageBoxResult.LeftButton:
            PlaceCall(clickedFavorite.Name, clickedFavorite.PhoneNo);
            break;
        case CustomMessageBoxResult.RightButton:
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => SendText(clickedFavorite.PhoneNo)));
            break;
    }
};
```

Comment: That did not work me, unfortunately. I think @user1767746 has a point; that the app is being disposed of, when navigating away from itself.

Answer (score 1):

My 0.02$: this is a bug in the CustomMessageBox. They're keeping lots of singletons alive there and a good timing bug doesn't do that a world of good. Agreed with KooKiz that you can't work around with that without either fixing CustomMessageBox or waiting until the CustomMessageBox finishes its thing. From my ad-hoc testing it requires anywhere between 2-6 Dispatcher.BeginInvoke() until those actions finish. Instead, maybe consider using DispatcherTimer and wait 256MS which should be enough time.

```
private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var msgBox = new CustomMessageBox()
                 {
                     Caption = "foo",
                     Message = "bar",
                     LeftButtonContent = "baz",
                     RightButtonContent = "goo",
                     IsFullScreen = false,

                 };


    msgBox.Dismissed += (s, args) =>
    {
        DispatcherTimerHelper.InvokeReallySoon(() =>
        {
            new SmsComposeTask()
            {
                Body = "foo",
                To = "bar"
            }.Show();
        });

    };

    msgBox.Show();
}


public static class DispatcherTimerHelper
{
    public static void InvokeReallySoon(Action action)
    {
        var t = new DispatcherTimer() {Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(256)};
        t.Tick += (s, args) => action();
        t.Start();
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried using this method of yours - and here's what happens. When my messagebox triggers the dismissed event, I'm redirected to the SMS application, which is right. I press back to get back to my app. Here's the funny thing: it briefly shows my app, then switches back to the SMS app, and I can do this a few more times before my app shows up and stays on the screen.

Comment: Right, make sure to unregister your event handler before redirecting to the SmsComposeTask. And register that event handler only prior to calling Show().

Answer (score 0):

The problem just happen in wp8.
I use the same code in wp7, nothing wrong happens.

Use Code4fun messagebox is a good choice，but is Button Click handler you need to call

```
  MessagePrompt.Hide();
```

to close the MessagePrompt.

Answer (score 0):

used a boolean on the dismissed event to define which button had been pressed. I then implemented the code I would of implemented in the dismissed event in the Unloaded event instead. This seemed to solve the issue.

i.e

```
    messageBox.Dismissed += (s1, e1) =>
    {
        switch (e1.Result)
        {
            case CustomMessageBoxResult.LeftButton:
                {
                    delete = true ;
                }
                break;
            case CustomMessageBoxResult.RightButton:
                break;
            case CustomMessageBoxResult.None:
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    };

    messageBox.Unloaded += (s1, e1) =>
    {
        if (delete)
            DeleteWorkout();
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug. 
It was fixed in the latest version.
Remove the reference and install the toolkit again.